# Oracle Import call procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, impdp

I'm using an Oracle 11g database and I used to run the below script before performing an import data pump command `impdp` since there are constraints in data when restoring the database due to foreign keys.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare

begin

for c1 in (select table_name, constraint_name from user_constraints) loop
    begin
        execute immediate ('alter table '||c1.table_name||' disable constraint '||c1.constraint_name);
    end;
end loop;

for t1 in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
    begin
        dbms_ouput.put_line(t1.table_name);
        execute immediate ('truncate table '||t1.table_name);
    end;
end loop;
```

My question is that, is there any way to automate this manual process so that whenever I execute the import data pump script, a stored procedure / function will execute first?

**For example:**

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/impdp ..... TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE .... ACTION_FIRST=STOREDPROC_CLEANUP_FIRST
```

Comment: You can always batch automate this, so that you run your disable/enable constraints script before/after the import.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle also provides data pump APIs. You can write a stored procedure to import the data. As part of that stored procedure, you can first disable constraints and then run import using data pump API.